# What happens in the end of netflix movie "DEATH NOTE"?

Tags: ending, death-note

In the end, when light is in hospital in his bed, Ryuk laughs and says "You humans are so interesting" and then the movie ends? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Probably nothing special, he says that a lot in the anime, and he says because he finds interesting to observe what humans do in given situations, that's why he sent the death note to the Earth (also because he was bored).